# 1. url_for() function not working. 2. blockcontent, endblock tags are shown as text in output, extends tag doesn't extend child file to parent file

Tags: python, flask

Problem 1: url_for() functions is not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Flask App</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static',filename='css/main.css')}}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
        <div class="container">
        <h1 class="logo">Ardit's web app</h1>
            <strong><nav>
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li><a href="{{ url_for("home") }}">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{{ url_for("about") }}">About</a></li>
                </ul>
        </nav></strong>

        </div>
        </header>
        <div class="container">
            {%block content%}
            {%endblock%}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Problem 2: block content and endblock tags are shown as plain text in the output and extends tag does not extend the code from child file to parent file.

```
{%extends "layout.html"%}
{%block content%}

<div class="about">
    <h1>My About page</h1>
    <p1>This is a test website.</p1>
</div>

{%endblock%}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was opening the layout.html file earlier and wondering if code was wrong but I needed to access the "localhost:5000" on the web browser.
And that was the mistake I was making.

Answer (score -1):

The following lines do not work because you use " too often

```html
<li><a href="{{ url_for("home") }}">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="{{ url_for("about") }}">About</a></li>
```

try:

```html
<li><a href="{{ url_for('home') }}">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="{{ url_for('about') }}">About</a></li>
```

Regarding your second problem I would suggest you seperate the `{%` from the rest of the statement:

```html
{% block content %}
```

Comment: Thx for ur input, but still nothing has changed, problems persist.

Comment: Show the layout.html please. The url_for-problem was not solved either? And also your folder structure. At the same level of routes.py you have a folder called static with a subfolder called css in which main.css is stored? Also the terminal output of the tried url_for-methods would be nice

Comment: I seem to have figured out the problem, and I have moved on. Thanks again(got a very quick response).

Comment: Then please add an answer how you figured out the problem so other users in the future might benefit from your problem

Comment: Okay I shall add an answer.

Comment: @Lenntror

this wont solve anything, flask will render the {{}} content first and the client will only become the data with the rendered content sent, there wont be any problems with the "" only the linter may cause an issue if its not set to django ...

(addressed at the answer not at any comment ...)